# confused on my group by sum query

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

This is my first group by and I'm trying to do the following:

1. Group by Branch, Account, and Reference Number
2. Add the grouped items together, then sum up the groups column TaxAmount and Amount as the total column.

Here is what I have but it's not compiling:

```
SELECT        SUM(SUM(Amount) + SUM(TaxAmount)) AS Total
FROM            Truck.PpsTransaction
GROUP BY ReferenceNumber, Branch, AccountNumber
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT ReferenceNumber, Branch, AccountNumber, SUM(Amount + TaxAmount) AS Total
  FROM Truck.PpsTransaction
 GROUP BY ReferenceNumber, Branch, AccountNumber
```

Answer (score 0):

Rollup should work well in this case:

```
SELECT   ReferenceNumber, Branch, AccountNumberReferenceNumber,
         SUM(Amount) GroupAmount, Sum(TaxAmount), GroupTax,
         SUM(Amount + TaxAmount) AS GroupTotal
FROM     Truck.PpsTransaction
GROUP BY ReferenceNumber, Branch, AccountNumber WITH ROLLUP
```